# How can I install a utility spigot so it's oriented the right way?

Tags: faucet, copper, pipe-fitting

I fitted new nozzle bibtap (same brand) onto new bibtap wall flange (same shop). I used PTFE tape, with Pipe joint lubricant (could not source Pipe joint compound) on both fittings. One fitted vertically, but the other, will not turn beyond what is shown in the picture.

What is the solution? I used Pipe joint lubricant for potable water, which worked in sealing the joint. Only PTFE (clockwise, facing male thread, 3 turns, 6 turns) was leaking.

[image]

[image: Bibtap1b]

[image: Bibtap2]

Comment: Usually with threaded pipe fittings, there is too loose(leaks), tight enough(no leaks), and too tight(wrong position).  There is usually some range of movement if done right.

Comment: If you turn that hose bib back so that it's upright, does it leak? It's not even a 1/2 turn, and odds are it'll be just fine.

Comment: I just turned it backwards to a vertical position. It does not leak, but turning the lever, makes the faucet turn also. I then put 8 turns of PTFE tape, it is stopping almost at the same place.

Comment: Is it hand tight or wrench tight.  If only hand tight, then a wrench should be able to give one more turn.

Comment: It is hand tight. I can try to use the plumbing pliers, but I hope it does not crack or damage the copper wall flange, or the brass bibtap. I tried the pliers, but it is already vise tight.

Comment: @crip659 half a turn so it points down...

Comment: Should have at least one safe full turn after hand(no wrench) tight, more than one turn is where concern begins.  Would remove to check that the threads are not damaged.

Comment: The question title asks a different question than the body: Why they're different vs how to fix. Answering why: The faucet body appears to be a cast metal body, which is then tapped for pipe threads. While it's possible to mechanically ensure that the pipe threads start at the same point on each body (more expensive), it is also possible that the tap cuts at the point where the cutting edge happens to grab first, so the threads could start at any point on the body. Same could apply to the wall outlet threads. Final tightening point could thus be anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the PTFE tape and clean the treads.

Now screw it on (hand only), use some silicon grease (or even olive oil) to make it go easy.

To see how far it goes and the position it ends up at.

That should tell you how much you can screw it on with PTFE tape, by hand and then last turn 1/4 turn with wrench to tighten it.